# Apache Camel: Unable to register shutdown hook due to JVM state

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using Camel to route Activemq messages.
Camel is boot with org.apache.camel.Main class like this:

```
public class SDaemon {

    private org.apache.camel.Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SDaemon sDaemon = new SDaemon();
        sDaemon.boot();
    }

    public void boot() {
        try {
            main = new Main();
            main.enableHangupSupport();

            PooledConnectionFactory p = new PooledConnectionFactory();
            p.setMaxConnections(8);
            p.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(500);

            ActiveMQComponent comp1 = activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616");
            comp1.setUsePooledConnection(true);
            comp1.setConnectionFactory(p.getConnectionFactory());

            ActiveMQComponent comp2 = activeMQComponent("tcp://192.168.10.103:61616");
            comp2.setUsePooledConnection(true);
            comp2.setConnectionFactory(p.getConnectionFactory());

            main.bind("activemq", comp1);                                               //ToGet
            main.bind("activemq2", comp2);                                              //ToInOut
            main.bind("activemqException", activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616")); //OnException

            main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

            System.out.println("Starting Camel(SDaemon). Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
            main.run();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

**problem:** when I send `Ctrl+C` to shutdown the camel, it logs this warning:

```
Unable to register shutdown hook due to JVM state
```

Why? and how to fix this?

Comment: Most likely the library you are calling tries to add a shutdown hook after it has started shutting down.  Most likely this is a bug in the library. I would ask a forum for the library involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page about shutting camel down gracefully - http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html

You can suppress the warning using:

```
context.getShutdownStrategegy().setSuppressLoggingOnTimeout(true);
```